# Regarding Mailman gem in Rails Email inbound processing

Tags: email, inbound

I need to work on Email receiving and inbound processing. 
But I don't know how to run the Email server to receive mail.
I'm searching for the way to find a solution for setting up email server to receive mail.

Can Any one please suggest how to configure the working of Mailman gem for receiving emails and inbound processing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd delegate the "mail server bit" to an existing mail server like GMail and use something like mailman to interact with it via the POP protocol.

Ryan bates just posted a tutorial on mailman to railscasts.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman

It's available to pro users only though, but his screencasts are top notch and well worth the money!